# Is there a more efficient query for specific, non-consecutive dates in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to query a table for all rows that match a few specific dates. The dates are not consecutive and returning data for the entire date range is not desired. The number of specific dates can be quite large, a couple of hundred. The `Date` field is indexed, so I'd like to make use of it.

Converting the `Date` field into a string and querying on string comparison feels a bit lazy/non-performant and discards any indexing. Something like this (below) works correctly but I am concerned about performance and scanning the table:

```
SELECT Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume FROM minuteBarTable 
WHERE DATE(Date) IN ('2004-07-13','2011-09-01','2007-12-12');
```

Using a block of '**OR**'s has the right effect and correct result, but I'd like to find a more elegant/scalable approach. It can become a bit unwieldy with hundreds of dates:

```
SELECT Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume FROM minuteBarTable 
WHERE Date='2004-07-13' OR Date='2011-09-01' OR Date='2007-12-12';
```

Is the block of '**OR**'s the more efficient approach here?

Comment: Try `EXPLAIN` on the 2 requests to compare what your MySQL does.

Comment: I recommend you remove the DATE() function from around your Date column in that first query. The `Date IN (list)` and `OR = ` patterns are equivalent, there should be no difference in the generated execution plan. The ordering of the date values specified in the IN list or in the OR list may have a minor impact on performance for index seeks on large tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the two SQLs above:

```
SELECT Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume FROM minuteBarTable 
WHERE Date IN ('2004-07-13','2011-09-01','2007-12-12');
```

This way MySQL can use the index on `Date`. And (according to O'Reilly's *High Performance MySQL*) `IN` is usually better than multiple `OR`s, because the query optimizer sorts the arguments in the `IN` list, so it will be faster to find the results in the index (which is sorted as well).